# Requests to server have erratic behaviour just for one service

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I have the following piece of code in my ionic app:

```
var req = {
  method: 'PUT',
  dataType: "json",
  url: loginservice.getServerAPI()+'/restaurants/'+$scope.currentRu.id+'/menu',
  data: response,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "Authorization" : "Bearer "+loginservice.gettoken()
  }
};

$http(req)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
  $state.go('wtf.thanks');
  return data;
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
  console.log(data);
  return "error";
});
```

};

Each time, I get an error that is different each time while the request is exactly the same.

[image: network errors]

Here is the related API code:

**routes/restaurants.js**:

```
router.route('/:id/menu')
  .put(restaurantController.updateRestaurantMenu);
```

**controllers/restaurant.js**:

```
exports.updateRestaurantMenu = function(req, res) {
  RestaurantModel.findOne({'id': req.params.id}, function(err, restaurant) {

    if (!err) {
      // update restaurant queue
      restaurant.menus = req.body.menus;
      restaurant.save(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
          return res.send(restaurant);
        } else {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(400).send(err);
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
  });
};
```

All I get in my logs is:

```
...
OPTIONS /api/restaurants/174/menu 200 1.742 ms - 3
OPTIONS /api/restaurants/174/menu 200 0.928 ms - 3
...
```

Instead of something like:

```
...
OPTIONS /api/restaurants/174/menu 200 1.742 ms - 3
PUT /api/restaurants/174/menu 200 1.742 ms - 3
OPTIONS /api/restaurants/174/menu 200 1.742 ms - 3
PUT /api/restaurants/174/menu 200 0.928 ms - 3
...
```

CORS is handled.

**app.js**:

```
// allow cross domain
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
};
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

As for now, it is the only `PUT` request that behaves this way. I have other `PUT` requests that work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem was due to the send of a token (for Basic Auth purposes) that was way too big apparently. This was due to a problem in the code but wasn't spotted before because the token wasn't big enough before to break things.